# direct video streaming from s3 to ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to ios development and creating the application which will stream videos from amazon s3 to ios device moreover I store videos in mp4 format.After searching for a while I came to know that HLS is possible solution but how can directly stream mp4 videos from s3 to ios?

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Have you done some research for this ? What have you found yourself ?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne I came to know that it is possible to stream video using HLS but for that I need  to convert it into m3u8 format by using some transcoder(like aws transcoder) but could not able to find direct solution.

Comment: @Sandeep please answer the above question i have the same issue which i could not able to find direct solution instead of converting file to .m3u8 format. simply without using HLS how to stream the mp4 videos  from direct s3 to iOS?